# How to check which if an input array is the most similar to a list of arrays in a faster method if the length of list of arrays is very large?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dtw

I have a list containing many lists. I use a dtw approach using the fastdtw python package to calculate the distance between an input list and the lists inside the list. This gives me a list of distances from which I choose the minimum value and estimate it as the one closest to the input array. This process works but it is CPU intensive and time consuming if the number and the length of lists are large.

```
from fastdtw import fastdtw
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

inputlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
complelte_list = [[1,1,3,9,1],[1,2,6,4],[9,8,7,4,2]]
dst = []
for arr in complete_lists:
   distance, path = fastdtw(arr,inputlist,dist=ssd.euclidean)
   dst.append(distance)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the closest, and not necessary all distances, build a tree, e.g.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

inputlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
complelte_list = [[1,1,3,9,1],[1,2,6,4,5],[9,8,7,4,2]]

tree = BallTree(np.array(complelte_list), leaf_size=10, metric='euclidean')
```

And query with

```
distance, index = tree.query(np.expand_dims(np.array(inputlist),axis=0), k=1, return_distance=True)
```

Which returns the `distance` to the closest `k=1` and also the `index`, e.g.

```
print('Most similar to inputlist is')
print( complelte_list[ index[0][0] ] )
```

If Speed is important, you can tweak `leaf_size=10` and try what works for your size. Building the tree also takes time so make sure that is part of your benchmark as well if this makes sense in your case.